# Customizing rosh initialization

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I notice that rosh doesn't seem to exactly have the same initialization behavior as ipython.  For example, in ~/.ipython/ipythonrc, I have the line:
importmod os sys

So if I start ipython, I have the os module available in the interactive namespace.   But with the same setup, starting rosh does not make those names available.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10459/customizing-rosh-initialization/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a bug in rosh.   The rosh loader for the shell needs to import os and sys.  In order to be 'clean', it then deletes os and sys.

Here's a patch that I think resolves this peculiarity (needs more testing):

```
diff -r 35d8b08984d6 shell.py
--- a/shell.py  Fri Jul 01 12:45:40 2011 -0700
+++ b/shell.py  Fri Jul 01 12:45:42 2011 -0700
@@ -10,6 +10,14 @@
 # import all symbols after initialization
 from rosh import *
 
+try:
+    cleanup_os = 'os' not in sys.modules
+    cleanup_sys = False
+except:
+    import sys
+    cleanup_os = 'os' not in sys.modules
+    cleanup_sys = True
+    
 import os, sys
 plugins = sys.argv[1:]
 
@@ -39,7 +47,9 @@
         del _f
 
 del plugins
-del sys
-del os
+if cleanup_sys:
+    del sys
+if cleanup_os:
+    del os
 del _roshrcp
 del _rosenv
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0